# Problem with Django and accounts in my linux server

Tags: django, postgresql

Im working in this django project with a partner in a server. When he is logged with his account and tries to execute `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` this is what he gets:

```
    Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 25, in <module>
    import psycopg2 as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 121, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 207, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 29, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

Whe I run it with my account it works good. I have already tried to reinstall psycopg2 logged with his account and this is what I got:

```
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (2.7.7)
```

I went to postgres and created a role for him with the same user name and password and still doesn't work. He has all permissions granted for files and Database.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes psycopg2 fails, you need to install binary version.
Try this: `pip uninstall psycopg2` and then `pip install psycopg2-binary`

Comment: It didnt work, do I have to install it in his account?

Comment: Wait,  can you confirm both you and your friend are using the same virtualenvironment?

Comment: Yes we used it, actually your solution worked fine but i had to use pip3 instead of pip. Thanks you!